# Bootstrap messing up my VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I have a very simple page with 2 buttons and one dropdown, and its working fine. The moment i add library files of Bootstrap, it completely messes up my VF page. 
Reason for Bootstrap addition: I want to open a modal on a button click. That piece i have figured out, but not able to fix my page. Here are my VF and Apex:

`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
// ** THE TROUBLING LINE. 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

New quote generated when old one is more than 5 days old

```
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <apex:outputText >If not available, contact your local Admin</apex:outputText>
    <br/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selQuote}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!avlQuot}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    <br/><br/>       
    <apex:commandButton value="Replace" action="{!repQuote}"  /> 

</apex:form>
```

`

APex:

```
public with sharing class ReplaceQCont {

public String selectedQuote {set; get;}


public ReplaceQCont() {



}

public ReplaceQCont(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}


public void requestNew(){

    Id contractId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    Contract__c contract = getContractDet(contractId);
    ConP__c ConP = getConP(contractId);
    List<Site__c> SiteList = getCSiteList(contractId); 
    Quant_Term__c qtp = getqtp(contractId);

    SendEmail(contract, ConP, SiteList, qtp);



}





public List<SelectOption> getAvailableQuotes(){
    List<SelectOption> quotes = new List<SelectOption>();

    Id contractId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Contract__c contract = [SELECT Id, Account__c 
                                FROM Contract__c
                                WHERE Id = :contractId];

    if(contract != null){
        List<Quote__c> qList = [SELECT Id, Name
                                            FROM Quote__c
                                            WHERE Account__c = :contract.Account__c]; 

        if(qList.size() > 0){
            for(Quote__c q : qList){
                quotes.add(new SelectOption(q.Id,q.Name));    
            }

        } else {
            quotes.add(new SelectOption('-1','No Quotes Available'));

        }




    return quotes;
} 

@TestVisible
private Contract__c getContractDet(Id contractId){

    ContractV2__c contract = [SELECT Account_Legal_Name__c,Contract_Number__c,Contract_Start_Date__c,Contract_End_Date__c, Owner.Name,Quote_Requested__C
                                FROM Contract__c
                                WHERE Id = :contractId ];

    return contract;
}

SendEmail(contract, ConP, SiteList, qtp){

// send mail code here
}
```

}

Messed up page 
[image: side bar is extremely enlarged]

Comment: You will need to scope your Bootstrap styles. [Limit the scope of bootstrap styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is meant to be a site theme, not really embedded inside of a page. However, there are workarounds if you're willing to do the work.

The easiest solution I've found is mentioned as follows:

## Clone Repo

Grab the most recent version of [Bootstrap](http://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) by cloning it locally.

## Modify LESS File

Modify `bootstrap.less` by putting a wrapper around it:

```
.bootstrap-scope {
    //put bootstrap @includes in here
}
```

## Make

Recompile Bootstrap so that LESS patches in the scope.

## Upload

Place the file in Salesforce as a static resource

## Scope

Modify your Visualforce page to have a scoped Bootstrap:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_scoped)}" />
...
<div class="bootstrap-scope">
  ...
</div>
```